# How can I apply a draggable function on a column layout panel in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

```
var rulePanel = new Ext.Panel({
                       id:'rule-panel',
                       layout:'border',
                       defaults: {
                            split: true,
                        },
                       border:false,
                       closable:false,
                       frame:false,
                        items: [
                            ruleGrid,
                            {
                                height:225,
                                region:'south',
                                layout:'column',
                                items:[auditGrid,
                                displayGrid
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    });
```

Below is the logic I want to apply draggable on the panel where items are(auditGrid, displayGrid)

Comment: That looks like a JavaScript UI framework, not Grails/Groovy. I'd be better to tag the question with whatever the framework is.

Comment: Yes it's an extjs UI.. I can able to implement by using split = true, but the window is moving totally not enlarging..

Comment: There are two frames in the window one is above using border as a layout. Below there is one more window with two columns divided and there they used layout: column. So thing is I should make the horizontal divide draggable. Can some one help on this. How to apply the draggable functionality for a layout: column.!!!!

Comment: What are you looking for? A method for start drag, while dragging, end drag?

Comment: I want to drag the horizontal divide between two panels.. to enlarge the below panel. In the above code we can see clearly that two panels are there.. one is using layout as border other is using column as layout. So there will be a horizontal divide that horizontal divide I have to implement drag where the inverted arrows symbol comes right to minimize and maximize

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a portal layout.

Reference: [Ext Portal](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/portal/portal.html)